# ASP.NET beginner question: Need help regarding using some class library

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String userHost = Request.UserHostName
    }
```

This is fetching the IP address alright, but now I want to know the country of the visitor and USE that country name to redirect the visitor to some webpage accordingly.

I came across this library but have no clue how to use it in the project. Actually I do, but I am not sure so I am asking.

http://ipaddressextensions.codeplex.com/

When I download from the above the ZIP folder has a DLL file and an XML file. Now, what do I do with these two? Like include in the project. Then what do I type in the code file?

Something like the following.

```
if (countryName=="France")
{
    response.redirect("www.mysite.fr")
}
else
    if(countryName=="India")
    {
        response.redirect("www.mysite.in")
    }
```

and so on...

How do I go about it? Also do I really need to type SO many `if` blocks for ALL the countries. How do I shorten this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To shorten your code put all the countries in a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string,string>  dict;

public void Init(){
    dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    dict["India"] = "www.mysite.in";
    dict["France"] = "www.mysite.fr";
}

public string GetPage(string country){
    string result = dict["Default"];

    if(dict.ContainsKey(theKey)){
        result  = dict[theKey];
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Just add the reference and then the "using statement" and the API is yours to use.

You could even alter the above to take in an IP address.

First add the reference and the below `using` to your code.

```
using WorldDomination.Net;

public string GetPage(string ipAddress){
    string result = null;
    IPAddress ipAddress;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse(userHostIpAddress, out ipAddress))
    {
        string fullNameKey= ipAddress.Country();
        //Or you could use two letter code
        //string twoLetterKey = ipAddress.Iso3166TwoLetterCode();
        if(dict.ContainsKey(theKey)){
             result = dict[fullNameKey];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = dict["Default"];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: And to shorten it evenmore use initializer syntax. new Dictionary<string,string>{{contry1,url1},...,{countryn,urln}};

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a reference to the downloaded library (dll) to your project. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx for details on adding references.

"What you type in the code file" will depend wholly on the library itself. If you're not sure how to implement the features of the library I suggest checking out the test project included in the [source code repository](http://ipaddressextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) hosted on the CodePlex page. It should show you what methods you'll need to call. With any luck, the class and method structure is self-explanatory.

If you prefer not to use `if() { } else if() { }` blocks you can elect to use a [switch statement](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/switch-statement/) instead.

```
switch(countryName) {
     case "India":
        // do something
        break;
    case "France":
        // do something
        break;
    case "Japan":
        // do something
        break;
    case "Germany":
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        // do something
        break;
}
```

Comment: ok added the dll ..what's that xml for ? do I need to include that too in the project ?

Comment: Also..that dll file is stored on my desktop..if I add the reference in my project and then delete the dll from desktop..will it give error saying dll missing ?

Comment: @happysoul The XML file contains the library documentation. You don't need to reference the XML itself, but if you keep it in the same folder as the DLL IntelliSense will give you documentation for the class.

Comment: @happysoul The DLL file is automatically copied to the "bin" directory of the referencing project. So long as you don't delete it from the bin directory you should be fine- copy the XML file there too if Visual Studio failed to.

Comment: It saves the original location.  SO if you were to delete the file on your desktop, then clean you will lose the dll.  You should move the dll to some type of folder and include it in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://ipaddressextensions.codeplex.com/ site has given sample code for finding country. Once you found the country then compare it with your sub domains according to countries and then redirect it.
`    using System.Net;
     using WorldDomination.Net;

```
 string userHostIpAddress = "203.1.2.3";
 IPAddress ipAddress;
 if (IPAddress.TryParse(userHostIpAddress, out ipAddress))
  {
    string country = ipAddress.Country(); // return value: UNITED STATES
    string iso3166TwoLetterCode = ipAddress.Iso3166TwoLetterCode(); //return value: US
  }    `
```